# Bootstrap based site works on localhost but not on a webserver

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When I run everything on my localhost everything works but I can't figure out why it won't run on the webserver. The carousel does not even show and buttons don't work. But it all runs perfectly on localhost?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <!-- Website Title & Description for Search Engine purposes -->
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- Mobile viewport optimized -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">



        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="includes/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="includes/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Include Modernizr in the head, before any other Javascript -->
        <script src="includes/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      .carousel-indicators {
          foreground-color:#;
      }
      .carousel-indicators {
          background-color:#;
      }

      .greenbutton, btn {

        border:2px solid #0099cc;
        color: #0099cc;
        background:none;

      }
      span.glyphicon-home {
        font-size:1.6em; 
        color:orange; 
      }
      .navbar {height:80px; }

      .navbar {
          margin-bottom:0px !important;}

      .carousel {
       margin-top:70px !important 
      }

     .footer {
       background-color: #F90;
       font-color: white;
       font-size: 12px;
       padding: 15px;
   }

   .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open
   .dropdown-menu {
       background-color: #ffffff;
       color:#F90;
   }

    .navbar {
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #186ACC;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0.0.0.0.1);
        border-radius: 0px; 
    }


    .navbar-default {
        background-color: #ffffff
    }
    </style>    

    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container" id="main">

         <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar">
             <div class="container-fluid">



            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">

                         <li class="dropdown">
                             <a href"#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> "Your Roof Now" <strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                             <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                 <li>
                         <a href="..\public/clogin/login.php"
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span> Log-In</a>
                                 </li>
                                 <li>
                         <a href="http//www.theweathernetwork.com">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Weather Network</a>        
                                 </li>                             
                             </ul>

                         </li>


                     </ul><!-- end nav pull-right --> 








                 <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse pull-right">

                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                         <li class="active">

                         <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services                                 <strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                            <li>
                             <a href="#">Sorry, this section is being updated</a>
                            </li>

                              <li class="divider"></li>

                            <li>
                              <a href="#"></a>
                            </li>

                              <li class="divider"></li>

                            <li>
                              <a href="#"></a>
                            </li>
                                </li>                       
                        </ul>
                         </li>
                       </li>
                     </ul><!-- end dropdown-menu-->







                 </div><!--end nav-collapse -->

             </div><!--end container -->

         </div><!-- end navbar-->




         <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel">


         <ol class="carousel-indicators">
             <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
             <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
             <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>  
             <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#myCarousel"></li> 
         </ol>

         <!-- wrapper for slides -->
             <div class="carousel-inner">
                 <div class="item active" id="slide1">
                     <div class="carousel-caption">

                     </div><!-- end carousel caption -->
                 </div><!-- end item -->


                 <div class="item " id="slide2">
                     <div class="carousel-caption">

                     </div><!-- end carousel caption -->
                 </div><!-- end item -->


                 <div class="item" id="slide3">
                     <div class="carousel-caption">

                     </div><!-- end carousel caption -->
                 </div><!-- end item -->


                 <div class="item" id="slide4">
                     <div class="carousel-caption">
                     </div><!-- end carousel caption -->
                 </div><!-- end item -->

             </div><!--carousel-inner -->

             <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
             <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>

         </div><!-- end myCarousel -->


         <div class="row" id="bigCallout">
             <div class="col-12">

                 <div class="alert alert-success alert-block fade in" id="successAlert">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>

                     <h4>Answer</h4>
                     <h4>'Monier Tile' and 'Columbia Tile'.  If you own a tiled roof chances are your tiles are from one of these two manufacturers.  <p class="lead">In most cases we find matches for tiles that are no longer being manufactured but require replacement.</p> Click the 'x' to close</h4>
                 </div><!-- end alert -->
                <!-- visible only on small devices -->
                <div class="well well-small visible-sm">
                 <a href="tel:+1-855-336-6772" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> 1-855-336-6772</a>

                </div><!-- end well-small -->




                 <div class="well">
                     <div class="page-header">
                         <h2>Its ok. We Know A lot About Tile. <small><hr>Which two tile brands are most commonly found on homes throughout the lower mainland? Click the answer button.</small></h2>


                     </div><!-- end page-header -->


                     <a href="" class="btn btn-small btn-warning" id="alertMe">Answer</a>
                     <hr>


      <div>
      <a href="form.php" class="greenbutton btn btn-small btn-success btn-responsive text-center">Request Estimate</a> <hr> 
      </div> 
      <div>
      <p class="lead"style="text-center">Can't use the phone? -Submit a request for an estimate here instead!</p>
      </div>             
                 </div><!--end well -->
             </div><!-- end column 12 this is the section right below carousel -->

         </div><!-- end bigCallout -->


         <div class="row" id="featuresHeading">
             <div class="col-12">
                <h4>We're making some improvements just below in order to better serve our customers.</h4>
                <p class="lead">Sorry for any inconvenience. Please scroll down.</p>
             </div><!-- end col-12 -->
         </div><!-- end featuresHeading -->


         <div class="row" id="features">
             <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
                 <div class="panel">
                     <div class="panel-heading">
                         <h3 class="panel-title">Under renovation</h3>
                     </div><!--end panel-heading-->
                     <img src="images/squaretwo200x200.jpg" alt="HTML5" class="img-circle img-responsive centre-block">

                     <p></p>
                     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Being updated</a>
                 </div><!-- end panel -->
             </div><!-- end feature -->

             <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
                 <div class="panel">
                     <div class="panel-heading">
                         <h3 class="panel-title">Under renovation</h3>
                     </div><!--end panel-heading-->
                     <img src="images/squaretwo200x200.jpg" alt="CSS3" class="img-circle img-responsive centre-block">

                     <p></p>
                     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Being updated</a>
                 </div><!-- end panel -->
             </div><!-- end feaauture -->

             <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
                 <div class="panel">
                     <div class="panel-heading">
                         <h3 class="panel-title">Under renovation</h3>
                     </div><!--end panel-heading-->
                     <img src="images/squaretwo200x200.jpg" alt="Bootstrap 3" class="img-circle img-responsive centre-block">

                     <p></p>
                     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Being updated</a>
                 </div><!-- end panel -->
             </div><!-- end feaauture -->

         </div><!-- end features -->




         <div class="row" id="moreInfo">
              <div class="col-sm-6">

                 <div class="tabbable">
                     <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                         <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Introducing our 'Your Roof Now Portal' </strong><br></h4>-Another first for our customers.</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">'Water Shortage Update'</a></li>
                     </ul>
           <div class="tab-content>
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
     <img src="images/untitled-20.png" class="thumbnail pull-left img-responsive text-center">                   <small>As a customer you'll automatically recieve access to 'Your Roof Now'.</small>

     <small><br>With 'Your Roof Now' while the surface of your concrete or terra-cotta roof tiles is being restored you can monitor the restoration process by logging onto your account.  Whether your half way around the world doing business, or taking a vacation. At home or at work, via laptop, tablet, or smartphone, you'll see the changes, any time of day, anywhere you are.</small> You know what they say...seeing is believing!<br><p>Call today and discover how easy it is.  1-855-336-6772</p>                





                         </div><!-- end tab-pane -->

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">


         <h4>More about water restrictions </h4> 
        <p>In the event that water restrictions are in place, cleaning with water is permitted
        when done so for the purpose of painting or surface treatments.  We take pride in our work and in providing our customers with the information they need when they need it.  Click the link below for current water restrictions in the lower mainland.</p>    

                             <hr>

   <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span> Vancouver Water Restriction Table </a>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
     <div class="modal-dialogue">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       </div><!--end modal-header -->
             <div class="modal-body">
               <h4>Greater Vancouver Water Restriction Plan.</h4>

               <p>Guidelines we follow.</p>


               <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger pop" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Current Restriction" data-content="Level 1">Click for current water  restriction level</a>

                <img src="images/gvrd.png" class="thumbnail pull-left img-responsive text-center">
                                        <hr>







        <div class="modal-footer">
         <button class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>  
        </div><!-- end modal-footer -->      
                                   </div><!-- end modal-body -->
                              </div><!-- end modal-content -->
                         </div><!-- end modal-dialogue -->
                    </div><!-- end myModal -->


                </div><!-- end tab-pane -->
            </div><!-- end tab-content :this is content tabs will toggle!-->
        </div><!-- end tabbable --> 
     </div><!-- end col-sm-6 -->


     <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="well">
         <h4>September 2015 <br>'Question of the Month'</h4>

         <div class="list-group">
             <a href"#" class="list-group-item">
                 <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Question</h4>
                 <p class="list-group-item-text">"Why do the eavestroughs on our house clog every eight months even though we have <strong>no</strong> trees on our property."</p>
             <a href"#" class="list-group-item">
                 <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Answer</h4>
                 <p class="list-group-item-text">Moss builds up on roof tiles where there is shade (usually along the tile edges).  Over time once the buildup reaches a certain size pieces will continuously break off and get washed down into the gutters when its windy or raining.  Once you remove dirt and debris from your roof tiles you eliminate a major contributing source of dirt and debris being fed to your homes gutter system.</p>
             <a href"#" class="list-group-item">
                 <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"></h4>
                 <p class="list-group-item-text"></p>
         </a>        
       </div><!-- end list-group-->
       </div><!-- end well -->
      </div><!-- end col-sm-3 -->


      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="well">
         <h4>October 2015 <br>'Question of the Month'</h4>




         <div class="list-group">
             <a href"#" class="list-group-item">
                 <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Question</h4>
                 <p class="list-group-item-text">"What do you mean when you say, 'Low Pressure' cleaning?"</p>
             <a href"#" class="list-group-item">
                 <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Answer</h4>
                 <p class="list-group-item-text">'We use approximately 1600 psi when cleaning tiles.  Other companies use between 3000 and 5000 psi.  Some reputable tile manufacturers reccommend lower pressure when cleaning their tiles. </p>
             <a href"#" class="list-group-item">
                 <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"></h4>
                 <p class="list-group-item-text"></p>
         </a>        
       </div><!-- end list-group-->
       </div><!-- end well --> 
      </div><!-- end col-sm-3 -->



     </div><!-- end moreInfo -->


         <div class="row" id="moreCourses">

         </div><!-- end moreCourses -->


    </div><!-- end container -->






    <footer>
        <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-2">
                 <h6>Copyright &copy; 2015 {TerraCottaClean}</h6>
                 </div><!-- end col-sm-2 -->


                 <div class="col-sm-4">
                 <h6>About Us</h6>
                 <p>Located in Vancouver, Canada.  Specializing in concrete tile, terra-cotta tile restoration.</p>
                 </div><!-- end col-sm-4 -->


             <div class="col-sm-2">
                 <h6>Navigation</h6>
                 <ul class="unstyled">
                      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="..\public/clogin/login.php">Login Page</a></li>
                      <li><a href="form.php">Contact</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div><!-- end col-sm-2 -->


                 <div class="col-sm-2">

                     <h6>Gotta Clean Your TerraCotta?</h6>
                     <h6>1-855-336-6772</h6>
                      <div>

                    </div>


                </div><!-- end col-sm-2 -->


             </div><!-- end row -->






        </div><!-- end container -->
    </footer>


    <!-- All Javascript at the bottom of the page for faster page loading -->

    <!-- First try for the online version of jQuery-->

    <!-- If no online access, fallback to our hardcoded version of jQuery -->
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="includes/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script src="includes/js/script.js"></script>

     <script>
     $('#send_btn').popover({content: 'Thank you'},'click');
     </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide a link to the live/production site ?

Comment: @GreatScott. Check your path of Css and Java Script Files.

Comment: Fix your bootstrap css paths.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example (you would need to add you custom CSS and JS files to your server).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

  <!-- Website Title & Description for Search Engine purposes -->
  <title>Some Title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">

  <!-- Mobile viewport optimized -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="includes/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Include Modernizr in the head, before any other Javascript -->
  <script src="includes/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .carousel-indicators {
      background-color: #;
    }
    .greenbutton,
    btn {
      border: 2px solid #0099cc;
      color: #0099cc;
      background: none;
    }
    span.glyphicon-home {
      font-size: 1.6em;
      color: orange;
    }
    .navbar {
      height: 80px;
    }
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
    .carousel {
      margin-top: 70px !important
    }
    .footer {
      background-color: #F90;
      font-color: white;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      color: #F90;
    }
    .navbar {
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #186ACC;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0.0.0.0.1);
      border-radius: 0px;
    }
    .navbar-default {
      background-color: #ffffff
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="main">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
          <li class="dropdown"> <a href "#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> "Your Roof Now" <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="..\public/clogin/login.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span> Log-In</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="http//www.theweathernetwork.com"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Weather Network</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end nav pull-right -->

        <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse pull-right">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li> <a href="#">Sorry, this section is being updated</a> 
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- end dropdown-menu-->

        </div>
        <!--end nav-collapse -->

      </div>
      <!--end container -->

    </div>
    <!-- end navbar-->

    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active" id="slide1">
          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
          <!-- end carousel caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- end item -->

        <div class="item " id="slide2">
          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
          <!-- end carousel caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- end item -->

        <div class="item" id="slide3">
          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
          <!-- end carousel caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- end item -->

        <div class="item" id="slide4">
          <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
          <!-- end carousel caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- end item -->

      </div>
      <!--carousel-inner -->

      <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>  <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-next"></span></a> 
    </div>
    <!-- end myCarousel -->

    <div class="row" id="bigCallout">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-block fade in" id="successAlert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
          <h4>Answer</h4>
          <h4>'Monier Tile' and 'Columbia Tile'.  If you own a tiled roof chances are your tiles are from one of these two manufacturers.
          <p class="lead">In most cases we find matches for tiles that are no longer being manufactured but require replacement.</p>
          Click the 'x' to close</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- end alert -->
        <!-- visible only on small devices -->
        <div class="well well-small visible-sm"> <a href="tel:+1-855-336-6772" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> 1-855-336-6772</a> 
        </div>
        <!-- end well-small -->

        <div class="well">
          <div class="page-header">
            <h2>Its ok. We Know A lot About Tile. <small>
            <hr>
            Which two tile brands are most commonly found on homes throughout the lower mainland? Click the answer button.</small></h2>
          </div>
          <!-- end page-header -->

          <a href="" class="btn btn-small btn-warning" id="alertMe">Answer</a>
          <hr>
          <div> <a href="form.php" class="greenbutton btn btn-small btn-success btn-responsive text-center">Request Estimate</a>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="lead" style="text-center">Can't use the phone? -Submit a request for an estimate here instead!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end well -->
      </div>
      <!-- end column 12 this is the section right below carousel -->

    </div>
    <!-- end bigCallout -->

    <div class="row" id="featuresHeading">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h4>We're making some improvements just below in order to better serve our customers.</h4>
        <p class="lead">Sorry for any inconvenience. Please scroll down.</p>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- end featuresHeading -->

    <div class="row" id="features">
      <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
        <div class="panel">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Under renovation</h3>
          </div>
          <!--end panel-heading-->
          <img src="images/squaretwo200x200.jpg" alt="HTML5" class="img-circle img-responsive centre-block">
          <p></p>
          <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Being updated</a> 
        </div>
        <!-- end panel -->
      </div>
      <!-- end feature -->

      <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
        <div class="panel">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Under renovation</h3>
          </div>
          <!--end panel-heading-->
          <img src="images/squaretwo200x200.jpg" alt="CSS3" class="img-circle img-responsive centre-block">
          <p></p>
          <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Being updated</a> 
        </div>
        <!-- end panel -->
      </div>
      <!-- end feaauture -->

      <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
        <div class="panel">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Under renovation</h3>
          </div>
          <!--end panel-heading-->
          <img src="images/squaretwo200x200.jpg" alt="Bootstrap 3" class="img-circle img-responsive centre-block">
          <p></p>
          <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Being updated</a> 
        </div>
        <!-- end panel -->
      </div>
      <!-- end feaauture -->

    </div>
    <!-- end features -->

    <div class="row" id="moreInfo">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="tabbable">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Introducing our 'Your Roof Now Portal' </strong><br>
            -Another first for our customers.</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">'Water Shortage Update'</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
              <img src="images/untitled-20.png" class="thumbnail pull-left img-responsive text-center" alt=""> <small>As a customer you'll automatically recieve access to 'Your Roof Now'.</small>  <small><br>
            With 'Your Roof Now' while the surface of your concrete or terra-cotta roof tiles is being restored you can monitor the restoration process by logging onto your account.  Whether your half way around the world doing business, or taking a vacation. At home or at work, via laptop, tablet, or smartphone, you'll see the changes, any time of day, anywhere you are.</small> You
              know what they say...seeing is believing!
              <br>
              <p>Call today and discover how easy it is. 1-855-336-6772</p>
            </div>
            <!-- end tab-pane -->

            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
              <h4>More about water restrictions </h4>
              <p>In the event that water restrictions are in place, cleaning with water is permitted when done so for the purpose of painting or surface treatments. We take pride in our work and in providing our customers with the information they need when
                they need it. Click the link below for current water restrictions in the lower mainland.</p>
              <hr>
              <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span> Vancouver Water Restriction Table </a>
              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialogue">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <!--end modal-header -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <h4>Greater Vancouver Water Restriction Plan.</h4>
                      <p>Guidelines we follow.</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger pop" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Current Restriction" data-content="Level 1">Click for current water  restriction level</a> 
                      <img src="images/gvrd.png" class="thumbnail pull-left img-responsive text-center"
                      alt="">
                      <hr>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
                      </div>
                      <!-- end modal-footer -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end modal-body -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- end modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- end modal-dialogue -->
              </div>
              <!-- end myModal -->

            </div>
            <!-- end tab-pane -->
          </div>
          <!-- end tab-content :this is content tabs will toggle!-->
        </div>
        <!-- end tabbable -->
      </div>
      <!-- end col-sm-6 -->

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="well">
          <h4>September 2015 <br>
          'Question of the Month'</h4>
          <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Question</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">"Why do the eavestroughs on our house clog every eight months even though we have <strong>no</strong> trees on our property."</p>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Answer</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">Moss builds up on roof tiles where there is shade (usually along the tile edges). Over time once the buildup reaches a certain size pieces will continuously break off and get washed down into the gutters when its windy or raining. Once you
                remove dirt and debris from your roof tiles you eliminate a major contributing source of dirt and debris being fed to your homes gutter system.</p>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"></h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text"></p>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- end list-group-->
        </div>
        <!-- end well -->
      </div>
      <!-- end col-sm-3 -->

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="well">
          <h4>October 2015 <br>
          'Question of the Month'</h4>
          <div class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Question</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">"What do you mean when you say, 'Low Pressure' cleaning?"</p>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Answer</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">'We use approximately 1600 psi when cleaning tiles. Other companies use between 3000 and 5000 psi. Some reputable tile manufacturers reccommend lower pressure when cleaning their tiles.</p>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"></h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text"></p>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- end list-group-->
        </div>
        <!-- end well -->
      </div>
      <!-- end col-sm-3 -->

    </div>
    <!-- end moreInfo -->

    <div class="row" id="moreCourses"></div>
    <!-- end moreCourses -->

  </div>
  <!-- end container -->

  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <h6>Copyright &copy; 2015 {TerraCottaClean}</h6>
        </div>
        <!-- end col-sm-2 -->

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h6>About Us</h6>
          <p>Located in Vancouver, Canada. Specializing in concrete tile, terra-cotta tile restoration.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- end col-sm-4 -->

        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <h6>Navigation</h6>
          <ul class="unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="..\public/clogin/login.php">Login Page</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="form.php">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- end col-sm-2 -->

        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <h6>Gotta Clean Your TerraCotta?</h6>
          <h6>1-855-336-6772</h6>
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <!-- end col-sm-2 -->

      </div>
      <!-- end row -->

    </div>
    <!-- end container -->
  </footer>

  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom JS -->
  <script src="includes/js/script.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#send_btn').popover({
      content: 'Thank you'
    }, 'click');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In your first stylesheet CDN link below, the equals sign is missing after `HREF`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Correct link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

*You also have duplicate Bootstrap CSS, JS and jQuery loading between CDNs and locally served files; you only need one or the other (jQuery fallback may be the exception).

**As a sidenote, you also have a great deal of invalid HTML, most prominently `href"#"` (again, there needs to be an equals sign after `HREF`).

Comment: oh ok thank you/the invalid html iie: styles and hrefs are some areas in transition as I am changing a few things there.  I added the cdns about an hour ago in desperation.  prior to adding the cdns in the header it did not work either.  (sorry I failed to mention these things earlier)  But regardless of these aforementioned items ie:the cdns/the page did not function.  Any other help appreciated, thanks again.

Comment: I also tried /via bootstrap website/using their exact js and googleapi and jquery lines but they did not work either, and then I kept trying changing the lines of reference so now all the variations.  If anyone could help via js fiddle I would owe them a debt of gratitude.

Comment: If you look at my answer you can see the working code just like a jsfiddle but directly on SO; click "Run code snippet", then "Full page". And you should consider posting a link to your site because at this point it's just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Carousel still not showing up/but shows on testing server and when I run the site root on my android tablet via html app. Does anyone else have any reccomendations regarding that problem?

Answer (score 0):

The carousel has no content - try adding some images ;)  I ran it through Firebug with some content and it works fine. It wouldn't hurt to tidy the code up and fix all the errors the other guys have pointed out.

You're also missing the following files so either delete the links or add the files:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - /includes/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - /includes/css/styles.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - /includes/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - /includes/js/script.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - /images/untitled-20.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set path of bootstrap css and javascript files.

```css
  .carousel-indicators {
          foreground-color:#;
      }
      .carousel-indicators {
          background-color:#;
      }

      .greenbutton, btn {

        border:2px solid #0099cc;
        color: #0099cc;
        background:none;

      }
      span.glyphicon-home {
        font-size:1.6em; 
        color:orange; 
      }
      .navbar {height:80px; }

      .navbar {
          margin-bottom:0px !important;}

      .carousel {
       margin-top:70px !important 
      }

     .footer {
       background-color: #F90;
       font-color: white;
       font-size: 12px;
       padding: 15px;
   }

   .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open
   .dropdown-menu {
       background-color: #ffffff;
       color:#F90;
   }

    .navbar {
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #186ACC;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0.0.0.0.1);
        border-radius: 0px; 
    }


    .navbar-default {
        background-color: #ffffff
    }
```

```html
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container" id="main">

         <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar">
             <div class="container-fluid">



            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">

                         <li class="dropdown">
                             <a href"#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> "Your Roof Now" <strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                             <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                 <li>
                         <a href="..\public/clogin/login.php"
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span> Log-In</a>
                                 </li>
                                 <li>
                         <a href="http//www.theweathernetwork.com">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Weather Network</a>        
                                 </li>                             
                             </ul>

                         </li>


                     </ul><!-- end nav pull-right --> 








                 <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse pull-right">

                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                         <li class="active">

                         <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services                                 <strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                            <li>
                             <a href="#">Sorry, this section is being updated</a>
                            </li>

                              <li class="divider"></li>

                            <li>
                              <a href="#"></a>
                            </li>

                              <li class="divider"></li>

                            <li>
                              <a href="#"></a>
                            </li>
                                </li>                       
                        </ul>
                         </li>
                       </li>
                     </ul><!-- end dropdown-menu-->







                 </div><!--end nav-collapse -->

             </div><!--end container -->

         </div><!-- end navbar-->




         <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel">


         <ol class="carousel-indicators">
             <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
             <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
             <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>  
             <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#myCarousel"></li> 
         </ol>

         <!-- wrapper for slides -->
             <div class="carousel-inner">
                 <div class="item active" id="slide1">
                     <div class="carousel-caption">

                     </div><!-- end carousel caption -->
                 </div><!-- end item -->


                 <div class="item " id="slide2">
                     <div class="carousel-caption">

                     </div><!-- end carousel caption -->
                 </div><!-- end item -->


                 <div class="item" id="slide3">
                     <div class="carousel-caption">

                     </div><!-- end carousel caption -->
                 </div><!-- end item -->


                 <div class="item" id="slide4">
                     <div class="carousel-caption">
                     </div><!-- end carousel caption -->
                 </div><!-- end item -->

             </div><!--carousel-inner -->

             <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
             <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>

         </div><!-- end myCarousel -->


         <div class="row" id="bigCallout">
             <div class="col-12">

                 <div class="alert alert-success alert-block fade in" id="successAlert">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>

                     <h4>Answer</h4>
                     <h4>'Monier Tile' and 'Columbia Tile'.  If you own a tiled roof chances are your tiles are from one of these two manufacturers.  <p class="lead">In most cases we find matches for tiles that are no longer being manufactured but require replacement.</p> Click the 'x' to close</h4>
                 </div><!-- end alert -->
                <!-- visible only on small devices -->
                <div class="well well-small visible-sm">
                 <a href="tel:+1-855-336-6772" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> 1-855-336-6772</a>

                </div><!-- end well-small -->




                 <div class="well">
                     <div class="page-header">
                         <h2>Its ok. We Know A lot About Tile. <small><hr>Which two tile brands are most commonly found on homes throughout the lower mainland? Click the answer button.</small></h2>


                     </div><!-- end page-header -->


                     <a href="" class="btn btn-small btn-warning" id="alertMe">Answer</a>
                     <hr>


      <div>
      <a href="form.php" class="greenbutton btn btn-small btn-success btn-responsive text-center">Request Estimate</a> <hr> 
      </div> 
      <div>
      <p class="lead"style="text-center">Can't use the phone? -Submit a request for an estimate here instead!</p>
      </div>             
                 </div><!--end well -->
             </div><!-- end column 12 this is the section right below carousel -->

         </div><!-- end bigCallout -->


         <div class="row" id="featuresHeading">
             <div class="col-12">
                <h4>We're making some improvements just below in order to better serve our customers.</h4>
                <p class="lead">Sorry for any inconvenience. Please scroll down.</p>
             </div><!-- end col-12 -->
         </div><!-- end featuresHeading -->


         <div class="row" id="features">
             <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
                 <div class="panel">
                     <div class="panel-heading">
                         <h3 class="panel-title">Under renovation</h3>
                     </div><!--end panel-heading-->
                     <img src="images/squaretwo200x200.jpg" alt="HTML5" class="img-circle img-responsive centre-block">

                     <p></p>
                     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Being updated</a>
                 </div><!-- end panel -->
             </div><!-- end feature -->

             <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
                 <div class="panel">
                     <div class="panel-heading">
                         <h3 class="panel-title">Under renovation</h3>
                     </div><!--end panel-heading-->
                     <img src="images/squaretwo200x200.jpg" alt="CSS3" class="img-circle img-responsive centre-block">

                     <p></p>
                     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Being updated</a>
                 </div><!-- end panel -->
             </div><!-- end feaauture -->

             <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
                 <div class="panel">
                     <div class="panel-heading">
                         <h3 class="panel-title">Under renovation</h3>
                     </div><!--end panel-heading-->
                     <img src="images/squaretwo200x200.jpg" alt="Bootstrap 3" class="img-circle img-responsive centre-block">

                     <p></p>
                     <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Being updated</a>
                 </div><!-- end panel -->
             </div><!-- end feaauture -->

         </div><!-- end features -->




         <div class="row" id="moreInfo">
              <div class="col-sm-6">

                 <div class="tabbable">
                     <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                         <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Introducing our 'Your Roof Now Portal' </strong><br></h4>-Another first for our customers.</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">'Water Shortage Update'</a></li>
                     </ul>
           <div class="tab-content>
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
     <img src="images/untitled-20.png" class="thumbnail pull-left img-responsive text-center">                   <small>As a customer you'll automatically recieve access to 'Your Roof Now'.</small>

     <small><br>With 'Your Roof Now' while the surface of your concrete or terra-cotta roof tiles is being restored you can monitor the restoration process by logging onto your account.  Whether your half way around the world doing business, or taking a vacation. At home or at work, via laptop, tablet, or smartphone, you'll see the changes, any time of day, anywhere you are.</small> You know what they say...seeing is believing!<br><p>Call today and discover how easy it is.  1-855-336-6772</p>                





                         </div><!-- end tab-pane -->

        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">


         <h4>More about water restrictions </h4> 
        <p>In the event that water restrictions are in place, cleaning with water is permitted
        when done so for the purpose of painting or surface treatments.  We take pride in our work and in providing our customers with the information they need when they need it.  Click the link below for current water restrictions in the lower mainland.</p>    

                             <hr>

   <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span> Vancouver Water Restriction Table </a>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
     <div class="modal-dialogue">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       </div><!--end modal-header -->
             <div class="modal-body">
               <h4>Greater Vancouver Water Restriction Plan.</h4>

               <p>Guidelines we follow.</p>


               <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger pop" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Current Restriction" data-content="Level 1">Click for current water  restriction level</a>

                <img src="images/gvrd.png" class="thumbnail pull-left img-responsive text-center">
                                        <hr>







        <div class="modal-footer">
         <button class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>  
        </div><!-- end modal-footer -->      
                                   </div><!-- end modal-body -->
                              </div><!-- end modal-content -->
                         </div><!-- end modal-dialogue -->
                    </div><!-- end myModal -->


                </div><!-- end tab-pane -->
            </div><!-- end tab-content :this is content tabs will toggle!-->
        </div><!-- end tabbable --> 
     </div><!-- end col-sm-6 -->


     <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="well">
         <h4>September 2015 <br>'Question of the Month'</h4>

         <div class="list-group">
             <a href"#" class="list-group-item">
                 <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Question</h4>
                 <p class="list-group-item-text">"Why do the eavestroughs on our house clog every eight months even though we have <strong>no</strong> trees on our property."</p>
             <a href"#" class="list-group-item">
                 <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Answer</h4>
                 <p class="list-group-item-text">Moss builds up on roof tiles where there is shade (usually along the tile edges).  Over time once the buildup reaches a certain size pieces will continuously break off and get washed down into the gutters when its windy or raining.  Once you remove dirt and debris from your roof tiles you eliminate a major contributing source of dirt and debris being fed to your homes gutter system.</p>
             <a href"#" class="list-group-item">
                 <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"></h4>
                 <p class="list-group-item-text"></p>
         </a>        
       </div><!-- end list-group-->
       </div><!-- end well -->
      </div><!-- end col-sm-3 -->


      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="well">
         <h4>October 2015 <br>'Question of the Month'</h4>




         <div class="list-group">
             <a href"#" class="list-group-item">
                 <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Question</h4>
                 <p class="list-group-item-text">"What do you mean when you say, 'Low Pressure' cleaning?"</p>
             <a href"#" class="list-group-item">
                 <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Answer</h4>
                 <p class="list-group-item-text">'We use approximately 1600 psi when cleaning tiles.  Other companies use between 3000 and 5000 psi.  Some reputable tile manufacturers reccommend lower pressure when cleaning their tiles. </p>
             <a href"#" class="list-group-item">
                 <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"></h4>
                 <p class="list-group-item-text"></p>
         </a>        
       </div><!-- end list-group-->
       </div><!-- end well --> 
      </div><!-- end col-sm-3 -->



     </div><!-- end moreInfo -->


         <div class="row" id="moreCourses">

         </div><!-- end moreCourses -->


    </div><!-- end container -->






    <footer>
        <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-2">
                 <h6>Copyright &copy; 2015 {TerraCottaClean}</h6>
                 </div><!-- end col-sm-2 -->


                 <div class="col-sm-4">
                 <h6>About Us</h6>
                 <p>Located in Vancouver, Canada.  Specializing in concrete tile, terra-cotta tile restoration.</p>
                 </div><!-- end col-sm-4 -->


             <div class="col-sm-2">
                 <h6>Navigation</h6>
                 <ul class="unstyled">
                      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="..\public/clogin/login.php">Login Page</a></li>
                      <li><a href="form.php">Contact</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div><!-- end col-sm-2 -->


                 <div class="col-sm-2">

                     <h6>Gotta Clean Your TerraCotta?</h6>
                     <h6>1-855-336-6772</h6>
                      <div>

                    </div>


                </div><!-- end col-sm-2 -->


             </div><!-- end row -->






        </div><!-- end container -->
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found on my own website was that your homepage (index.html in my case) has to link a CSS file by its full path.

All other files needed to refer to the local path of the CSS file (if they're in the same folder as the CSS, then just link to sample.css).

For reference, the website was imaginer.me. Use inspect element to check the `<head>`.